# Importing time data without time zone information and DST

Tags: timezone

This is fairly generic question about handling time zones.

My situation is as follows: I am importing *historic* logfile entries into database. The entries have timestamp in classic Unix epoch format and contain no time zone offset information. I know the time zone they were recorded with. The time zone observes daylight savings time. How do I handle importing these data into time zone aware database? Most of the entries are straightforward, but there's one problematic time -- when the DST ends (the time shifts one hour back making the last hour to be "re-run"). There are perfectly valid same timestamps that signify *different* times. Is there any agreed upon method how to handle this task?

Am I correct that at certain data inputs this problem is unresolveable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this problem is unresolveable. You need to know a few things - #1, when DST/ST occurs for these years (so some time library will be useful) and #2 be able to parse these logs in order. While importing, you are parsing the datetime using the library to determine if it was DST or ST. For the hour that happens right around DST transition, you play it back in sequential order and when an entry jumps 1 hour before the previous entry, you know this needs to be adjusted. This is assuming that your data is in sequential order and you can do that analysis. Not saying it is easy, but certainly possible. The only point that would be impossible to determine if there were only single log entries during the transition hour. You would have no way of knowing if it was before or after DST. Hopefully though your logs are noisy enough that you have a sample during that time before and after.

Since you did not write anything about language or any other details, I can't give you any specific implementations.

Comment: This is generic problem and does not need to consider any language specifics. The crux of the problem is that there is range of timestamp values that each represent <i>two</i> actual times and you simply don't know which is which. You might try to do some heuristics but they cannot be foolproof. Just consider that there's just one entry for the transition period in question -- you have no way to know if it is the DST or non-DST timestamp.

Comment: That is correct. You can only be certain if you witness a relapse during that time period. If there is only a single event recorded during that time period, you have no certainty whether it was before DST or after. But then you have to ask yourself, does the requirements of your project dictate that it matters? We're only talking about 2AM and 3AM on a Sunday early morning once a year? Can you allow that margin of error? I would guess that you have room for that margin of error or else the logs would have been kept more carefully.